# PdfReader constructor on Inputstream or Byte[] with interface ExternalDecryptionProcess

Tags: itext, itextpdf

I need to call the constructor of PdfReader with the interface ExternalDecryptionProcess  from an inputStream or byte array.

Is it possible to add a new constructor to the PdfReader class like the following:
`PdfReader(final InputStream is, Certificate certificate, final ExternalDecryptionProcess externalDecryptionProcess)`

OR

`PdfReader(final byte pdfIn[], Certificate certificate, final ExternalDecryptionProcess externalDecryptionProcess)`

The master constructor is private so I couldn't directly call it

Thanks
Jamil

Comment: So far, nobody has asked for such a constructor, so nobody added it. I'll make a ticket to add it for the next release.

Comment: I've added those two constructors to PdfReader. They will be included in the next release, planned for the week of May 4-8. Or you can checkout the code and build iText yourself on github or sourceforge.